# How to link to a specific part of a page

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, names

I have a rails app and one page is a 'command center' with links to a help center. Things like, signing up or new post, etc. How can i make it so that when you click on a link, not only does it redirect to the help center, but that specific section. I tried making my links, `link_to('/help#sigingup', 'Sign Up Help')` and then in the help i have `<h1 name='signingup'>Sign Up Help'`
Anyone know what i am doing wrong?

Comment: You have two correct answers. You should use `id` instead of `name`, even if you use HTML 4, which allows this attribute. By the way - which browsers did you test your page with? Firefox 6 ignores the `name`. I wonder which other also do?

Comment: And by the way - haven't you by accident swapped the attributes to `link_to`? The "Sign Up Help" should be the first attribute, and the url should be the second. In this case the answer from _John Beynon_ is also a correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use an anchor

for your link do something like;

```
link_to "Sign Up Help", help_path(:anchor => "signup")
```

this will give you a URL with #signup on the end.

and then in your help page where you want to be jumped to;

```
<a name="signup">Sign Up Help</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Partial links target IDs not Names

Make it `id="signingup"` instead of `name=`

that should work

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `id` attribute to create an anchor.

Have a read of the spec here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3

Comment: Well, the spec says that 'name' is still valid, and in some cases better than 'id'. ;-) I suppose the problem is that the newest browsers just stopped supporting the 'name' attribute.